# Multisite: List all Blogs alphabetically

Tags: multisite, sort, blog

Right now I do this …

```
<ul role="navigation" class="sektionen">
    <?php 
        $blog_list = wp_get_sites();
        foreach ($blog_list AS $blog) {
            global $blog_id;
            $currentblog = get_blog_details( $blog['blog_id'] );
            echo "<a class='subblog' href='".$blog['path']."' title='" . $currentblog->blogname . "'>".$currentblog->blogname."</a>";
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to list all Blogs alphabetically. How would I do that?

Comment: You can use [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) to sort your `$blog_list` array before your `foreach()` loop.

Comment: And in English: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: Hmmm. The `ca3.php.net` one shows up in English for me -- maybe because I'm in Canada? At any rate, I've changed the link in my 1st comment.

Comment: Can you guys give me an example of code? $blog_list is returning arrays as well, does this even work?